# Can I add values to config.properties file by hand in Java

Tags: java, properties, mapping

I want to keep a map of all the well known port numbers and it's associated services. I want to use the port number to get the protocol name. I don't want to use hashtable or map any anything like that.

I'm thinking of properties file as a good candidate for this(plz suggest if there is another good way)

So Google and saw many in getting and setting value to the properties file. What I want to know is whether I can add values this file by hand, that is open the file in a text editor and add key-values to it ?

example

80 = HTTP

443 = HTTPS

Answer (score 0):

You may use the the [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class for that. You can find a usage example [here](http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/readwrite-properties-files-in-java/231000005).

Comment: What I meant is not via program. Can I open the properties file in a file editor and edit the values ?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the property file by hand ,But it depends how you are loading the property file so that the changes are reflected.
1) if you are loading the property file via classpath (FAST).Then the property file is loaded when the app starts which means that any change in property file will not be reflected until you restart the app.
2) If you load the property file via filereader and then populate the property object(SLOW) then any change in the property file will be picked up by your app without restart

The example provided by guy boullet is good as is the apache commons library http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_properties.html